# Live action TV show from 90s where kid has a handheld PDA like device to solve problems

Tags: story-identification, tv

I'm looking for a TV show from the 90s (I guess) revolving around a group of kids that had one (or more) handheld PDA devices which helped them to solve quests.

The device could be use as a lockpicking device for a physical lock, for example.

It was a live action series, not animated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually watch this? Also, can you give any examples of the kind of quests the kids solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very likely the Australian [Mission Top Secret](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/MissionTopSecret). From the TVTropes description:

> A prominent and memorable feature of the series was the use of the futuristic spy-gadgets invented by Sir Joshua, most notably the PCU (Personal Communication Unit), a high-tech pocket computer, video-communicator, satnav and **lock pick** (basically a **smartphone** 15 years before the term was invented) that the Centauri members use to stay in touch with each other around the world.

Here's the [second season intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sAGsQISLjH8) in case the faces and theme song are recognizable.